# Oracle - How to select from LTRIM result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with column x that has varchar values like 'student_number=1234' and 'student_ticket_number=4321'

I used LTRIM to get only numbers, cause I need them to get students registration number

My query is something like:

```
select LTRIM(tb.col_x, 'student_number'),
       LTRIM(tb.col_x, 'student_ticket_number')
from table tb
where tb.condition = c
```

And it works, but now i need to get the numbers column ltrim created and use then in a join with table owner.students to get their registration number

Just tried like JNevill said, using ltrim at the join clause, but I got "invalid number" error, cause at this table the column is varchar, but at students table this key is number

Comment: You can use the `ltrim()` in the join like `INNER JOIN students ON LTRIM(tb.col_x, 'student_number') = students.id` but it isn't going to be fast. I would, if I were you, put some focus on revamping this schema so that `"student_number"` is stored on one field in `tb` and `1234` is stored in a second field so you can properly index and not slaughter your server's CPU with a million `ltrim()` running all day long.

Comment: i have no access to alter the schema... i will try the join like you said, since i'm getting only this month records and it will run only once

Comment: doesn't work... i got invalid number, i'm editing the question

Comment: I think you need to add an `=` to the end of that string your `ltrim`'ing by. Also you may have to `CAST` that ltrim too like `ON CAST(LTRIM(tb.col_x, 'student_number=')  AS INT) = students.id`

Comment: did not understand what you said... i think i need to add ' ' at the start and end of this varchar column

Comment: What does "is not working" mean? Did you get an error? No error, just wrong result? Try to never say these words, "is not working", ever again; they make no sense in technology. Explain exactly what is not working, and how it is not working.

Comment: sorry, i got "invalid number" error

Comment: The second argument to [`LTRIM`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions108.htm) is a set of characters (`'s'`, `'t'`, `'u'` etc), not an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget you can go the other way round, and isntead of stripping the text out of col_x to leave just a number, you can add text to the number (in the other table). I suspect this would be a more performant too:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  table tb
  INNER JOIN
  students s
  ON
    tb.col_x = 'student_number=' || s.registration_number
```

You can use OR to establish multiple links:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  table tb
  INNER JOIN
  students s
  ON
    tb.col_x = 'student_number=' || s.registration_number OR
    tb.col_x = 'student_ticket_number=' || s.ticket_number
```

If the number present in col_x respresents different things (eg it isn't always a student reg no) then this approach could work well. Perhaps thopugh consider, before building it into a production system, that you should use it as a one time op to clean up the db and have a student id in the `tb` table instead of always manipulating it out of/into a string

Edit: You mentioned your numbers are in different tables. Multiple joins may be required, or multiple queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  table tb
  INNER JOIN
  students s
  ON
    tb.col_x = 'student_number=' || s.registration_number
  INNER JOIN
  student_tickets st
  ON
    tb.col_x = 'student_ticket_number=' || st.ticket_number
```

Or if there isn't a direct relationship here and you get no results, you'll have to do separate queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  table tb
  INNER JOIN
  student_tickets st
  ON
    tb.col_x = 'student_ticket_number=' || st.ticket_number
```

Side note:

LTRIM isn't intended for removing strings from the left hand side of a string. It just so happens to work, but if you think about the way it works, you'll realise it's a poor solution. SUBSTRING would be faster

Comment: thanks, the problem now is that my student_ticket_number is at another table (student_ticket)

Comment: Extend the first query.. I'll give an example

Answer (score 2):

I would use `like`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table tb JOIN
     students s
     ON tb.col_x LIKE '%=' || s.registration_number;
```